# Python 3 SSL fails after OpenSSL install

Tags: openssl, discord.py, python-3.8, aiohttp, ubuntu-20.04

Whenever I try to run my discord.py discord bot after installing openssl
I get this massive error, as far as I can tell the gist of it is that it cannot find the certificate for Discord.  I tested with Bash and C++, and they connect fine, however I cannot connect to any servers via python. I have already reinstalled Certifi and CA-certificates, as well as installing PyOpenSSL and manually adding the signed keys.  What could be the issue and how could I fix it?

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/valkyrie_pilot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1050, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1080, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 529, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./betterbot.py", line 285, in <module>
    valkyriebot.run(TOKEN)
  File "/home/valkyrie_pilot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 718, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/home/valkyrie_pilot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 697, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/valkyrie_pilot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 660, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/home/valkyrie_pilot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 509, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/home/valkyrie_pilot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 293, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/valkyrie_pilot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/home/valkyrie_pilot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/valkyrie_pilot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/home/valkyrie_pilot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/valkyrie_pilot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/valkyrie_pilot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/home/valkyrie_pilot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/home/valkyrie_pilot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 971, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')]```
````

Comment: stackoverflow rules: include the important snippet directly into the question, don't force users to follow links.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is here probably because you have a new VPS.

I have found that the best fix is to run
`pip install certifi` *(Make sure you're using the correct version of Python for pip, can sometimes be pip3)*

Then when you are done just run:
`sudo update-ca-certificates`

If your wondering what **certifi** is, it's a package that comes preinstalled with requests, so if you have a fresh VPS it's not installed. It's a one time package so when it's done installing you should have the necessary certificates forever. If you want to check what it is by yourself, here is the [GitHub repository of `certifi`](https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi) and the [PyPi project of `certifi`](https://pypi.org/project/certifi)

Have a fantastic day and happy coding ^^

Comment: If you would read the question, this is my desktop PC, not a VPS, and I already tried reinstalling certifi and updating ca-certificates